# weird IIS 401 error Solution, Detailed vs. Custom?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, iis-7.5

I had 401 error on IIS 7.5. I searched for that error and I saw lots of people having the same error and still there is no straight solution for that. here are some links that I read for solving this error:

[Microsoft 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9239a89-fbee-4adc-b72f-7a6a9648331f/401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials?forum=winserversecurity) , 
[Microsoft 2](http://forums.iis.net/t/1201332.aspx?IIS%207%205%20Win2008%20Server%20R2%20401%20Unauthorized%20Access%20is%20denied%20due%20to%20invalid%20credentials%20) , 
[symantec 1](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/401-errors-console-after-75-upgrade) ...

...  Anyway I couldn't solve this error and I decided to change the error page to show more details for it. So I went to "Error Pages" on IIS manager and I edited 401 error feature settings and I selected "Detailed Errors" I restarted the web site ... and all of a sudden it is working!

[image]

But if I changed the Error responses to "details for local and custom for remote" or "custom error page" it will throw 401 error. 
is there anyone who know what is going on? any idea?

Comment: Same issue here. Would be useful if someone could help out

Comment: If you are still having the issue and you are using MVC then maybe this will help - 
After a lot of messing around, it turned out my issue was with a partial being called in the layout. The partial was in a controller that required auth. Therefore I simply added [AllowAnonymous] to that partial and it worked.

Comment: Thanks TimPalmer for your respond I will check to see if it would solve my problem or not, I will let you know.